# my ssh is OK,but mha ssh check is fail

Tags: centos, ssh, mysql-replication, ssh-keygen

CentOS 6.6 + MySQL MHA(0.56)\

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@slave2
```

and my SSH check is ok

```
[root@master ~]# ssh -v root@slave2
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to slave2 [192.168.233.133] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'slave2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = zh_CN.UTF-8
Last login: Wed Jun  1 06:56:32 2016 from master
```

and test ssh connection through command line,correct

```
[root@master ~]# ssh root@slave2
Last login: Wed Jun  1 22:55:06 2016 from 192.168.233.1
[root@slave2 ~]#
```

when I use mha ssh check(masterha_check_ssh script)，an error occurs "Permission denied (publickey,password)."

```
    [root@monitor ~]# masterha_check_ssh --conf=/etc/app1.cnf
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:52 2016 - [warning] Global configuration file /etc/masterha_default.cnf not found. Skipping.
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:52 2016 - [info] Reading application default configuration from /etc/app1.cnf..
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:52 2016 - [info] Reading server configuration from /etc/app1.cnf..
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:52 2016 - [info] Starting SSH connection tests..
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:53 2016 - [error][/usr/local/share/perl5/MHA/SSHCheck.pm, ln63] 
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:52 2016 - [debug]  Connecting via SSH from root@master(192.168.233.135:22) to root@slave2(192.168.233.133:22)..
    Permission denied (publickey,password).
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:52 2016 - [error][/usr/local/share/perl5/MHA/SSHCheck.pm, ln111] SSH connection from root@master(192.168.233.135:22) to root@slave2(192.168.233.133:22) failed!
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:53 2016 - [error][/usr/local/share/perl5/MHA/SSHCheck.pm, ln63] 
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:52 2016 - [debug]  Connecting via SSH from root@slave2(192.168.233.133:22) to root@master(192.168.233.135:22)..
    Permission denied (publickey).
    Thu Jun  2 04:25:53 2016 - [error][/usr/local/share/perl5/MHA/SSHCheck.pm, ln111] SSH connection from root@slave2(192.168.233.133:22) to root@master(192.168.233.135:22) failed!
    SSH Configuration Check Failed!
     at /usr/local/bin/masterha_check_ssh line 44
    You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

and this is my mha configuration, ssh_user is root ~
I have 5 servers —— master,slave1,slave2,slave3,monitor

```
[root@monitor bin]# cat /etc/app1.cnf
  [server default]
  user=root
  password=123456

  ssh_user=root

  master_binlog_dir= /data/mysql3306/logs/
  remote_workdir=/data/mysql3306/logs/mha_save_binlog
  secondary_check_script= /usr/bin/masterha_secondary_check -s slave3 -s slave2
  ping_interval=3
  #master_ip_failover_script=/script/masterha/master_ip_failover
  #shutdown_script= /script/masterha/power_manager
  #report_script= /script/masterha/send_master_failover_mail
  manager_workdir=/var/log/masterha/app1
  manager_log=/var/log/masterha/app1/app1.log

  [server1]
  hostname=master

  [server2]
  hostname=slave1

  [server3]
  hostname=slave2

  [server4]
  hostname=slave3
```

***This is has been making me crazy for 24 hours, can anybody help me?***

Comment: You probably  need to tell the `masterha` to use your private key (`/root/.ssh/id_rsa`).

Comment: @Jakuje how to do that ? add entry to /etc/app1.cnf ？

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use preshared keys ( between all cluster ) and use the `masterha_check_ssh` with public key authentication.

Comment: preshared keys is publickey right ? I have already done ssh no password

Comment: Does your `/etc/app1.cnf` have the `user`,`password`,`repl_user` and `repl_password` defined ?

Comment: yes,they are correct